# My PHP while loops ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)); displays several times instead of one time

Tags: php, mysql

The table is showing each lesson five times (the number of query lessons). I wish only for each to display once according to the If else statement. What is wrong with my code please?

```
<?php
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456'");

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

      if ($row['lesson']  == "Reproductive system 01a")
     {
    echo 'Reproductive system 01a Completed ';
   }
    else
     {
    echo '<a href="file:///D|/CC-Gate/localhost">Reproductive system 01a</a>';
    }
}

?>



 <?php



  $query = mysql_query("SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456'");

           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  if ($row['index_no'] !== '456' && $row['lesson'] !== "Fertilisation      process") { // this is redundant as  your query handles this
        echo '<a href="file:///D|/CC-Gate/localhost">Fertilisation process</a>';
   } else {
       echo 'Fertilisation process Completed';
   }
}
?>
```

This code is working:

```
<?php

       $query = mysql_query("SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456'");

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

         if ($row['index_no'] !== '456' && $row['lesson'] !== "pregnancy") { // this is redundant as  your query handles this
          echo '<a href="file:///D|/CC-Gate/localhost">pregnancy</a>';
       } else {
        echo 'pregnancy Completed ';
      }
      }
?>

<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        if ($row['lesson']  == "Birth process")
         {
            echo 'Birth process Completed ';
        }
         else
         {
            echo '<a href="file:///D|/CC-Gate/localhost">Birth process </a>Birth process Completed ';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: "Reproductive system 01a" how many lesson available in table and "Reproductive system 01a" lesson only one time show correct ?

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and will not work anymore. Use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `MySQLi` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have duplicate rows with same index_no
How many results does this query show?

```
SELECT index_no, count(index_no) as duplicate FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456' GROUP BY index_no
```

You have to deduplicate (delete old rows) and then add a unique key index to index_no

===

EDIT:

Well, in your comments you put that you have an error in this line, where mysqli requires 2 params...

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456' && lesson='Reproductive system 01a'");
```

That's because in mysql**i** you have to reference the connection, ex:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456' && lesson='Reproductive system 01a'") or die (mysqli_errro($mysqli));
```

Where `$mysqli` is your connection, such as this:

```
$mysqli = @mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die("Server Overloaded. Please try again in a few moments!");
```

Comment: I simple want the code to display "lesson completed"  or display the lesson's hyperlink if has yet to be finished. Getting the error "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in H:\xampp\htdocs\bps_register\BPS_menu_fadinglink_test01.php on line 68

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in H:\xampp\htdocs\bps_register\BPS_menu_fadinglink_test01.php on line 71

Comment: This is the code that has the problem which I can't figure out.   "$query = mysqli_query("SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456' && lesson='Reproductive system 01a'");


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
 
if ($row['index_no'] == '456' && $row['lesson'] == "Reproductive system 01a")
    
  {
        echo 'Reproductive system 01a Completed ';
    }
  else
  {
        echo '<a href="file:///D|/CC-Gate/localhost">Reproductive system 01a </a>';
    }
}""

Comment: What happens when you run the query: `SELECT index_no, lesson FROM c8_lessons_list WHERE index_no ='456' && lesson='Reproductive system 01a'` from phpmyadmin, or other administration tool?